# How to get Steam public key?

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, public-key, steam-web-api

For this method:

> ISteamUserAuth
>
> AuthenticateUser
>
> Version: 1
>
> HTTP Method: POST
>
> Parameters:
>
> Name: steamid
>
> Type: uint64
>
> Optional:
>
> Description: Should be the users steamid, unencrypted.
>
> Parameters:
>
> Name: sessionkey
>
> Type: rawbinary
>
> Optional:
>
> Description: Should be a 32 byte random blob of data, which is then
>   encrypted with RSA using the Steam system's public key. Randomness is
>   important here for security.
>
> Parameters:
>
> Name: encrypted_loginkey
>
> Type: rawbinary
>
> Optional:
>
> Description: Should be the users hashed loginkey, AES encrypted with
>   the sessionkey.

I need 3 parameters. For the second parameter `sessionkey`, I need to encrypt it using the Steam system's public key. How exactly do I get that?

After some research I figured out that I have to get a public key by using a certificate, and it should look like [this](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam/blob/master/lib/public.pub).

I am using php, and thus I am using this code to retrieve a public key from a certificate:

```
<?php
$pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('./cert.crt'));
$keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pub_key);
file_put_contents('./key.pub', $keyData['key']);
?>
```

I am confused as to which certificate do I use. Do I use the certificate of the Steam website? (`cert.crt` would be the certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt. I'd not tried it yet, but:

```
curl -X POST "http://store.steampowered.com/login/getrsakey/" 
     -d username="your_username"
```

Gives you a RSA key...